# What does Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword ORDER at [3:1] mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: sql

When I have an issue like this:

```
Expected end of input but got keyword ORDER at [3:1]
```

I don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Expected+end+of+input+but+got+keyword  a common thread to former questions with exactly the same issue is that we need to see the query that created the error. Without that query would just be guessing what was wrong. Please add your query into the question as formatted text (not an image).

Comment: by the way `[3:1]` means on row 3 at character 1, so there is a syntax error BEFORE row 3 satrts. e.g. there might be an unmatched parenthesis in a function call

Answer (score 1):

When you have an issue like that you would look where the ORDER keyword appeared in your query, and check/re-check if the syntax you used was correct for the database product you have. Presumably `[3:1]` is also trying to give more information, so you should check the product manuals/documentation relating to error messages to understand how to interpret. If you want others to check for you you need to provide the SQL text you used, and tag the particular rdbms product.

Googling the error message seems to return similar messages encountered for users of BigQuery. The error message may not be generated by the RDBMS product but by the front-end (the application/web-interface you used to type and submit the SQL command), and it may simply mean that you have more than one SQL statement submitted without the correct separator between them (like ';')??